# Nextjs 13 authentication between server component and separate backend

Tags: next.js, next.js13, clerk

I am unsure about how to make API calls from Nextjs 13 to my separate Python backend.

I have two scenarios:

- API call comes from client side component
- API call comes from server side component

The client side component has the correct session cookie from my auth provider (Clerk). So that case is pretty straight forward and I can authenticate the call in the Python backend.

However, when the call comes from the server side session cookies are not included. I could send a JWT token along. But that would add quite a bit of complexity.

What approach would you recommend in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same doubt. Not sure how to approch this. In my case the seperate backend can either send jwt token in response or as cookie. i want to get user data in server and send it to brower, to prevent flash screens.

**one possible solution**

When the external server sends jwt token ,Nextjs cant store it anywhere. it has to be maintained in user browser. so the flow would be

**Request**

user browser (login page) -> nextjs API -> External Server (Login route)

**Response**

external server (JWT TOKEN) -> nextJS API (SET cookie in user browser) -> user browser

from now on when ever you request to any page , you have cookie available to access in next [server component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiesgetname) , then make request to external server apis using the cookie

let me know if there is a better approch